# $f(z)=(\log(1-z))^2$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {a_n z^n} $ is the Taylor series of $f(z)$. Find $a_4$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

$f(z)=(\log(1-z))^2$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {a_n z^n} $ is the Taylor series of $f(z)$.  Find $a_4$.

The answer is $\frac{11}{12}$.  Can someone help me to explain why?

Comment: Hi and welcome to math SE. We usually don't give homework help until OP has told us what they've tried.

Comment: I tried to develop the ln(1-z) series but then I got a sum (sigma) in a power of 2 ..

Comment: A Taylor series centered at $z=0$ is also called a Maclaurin series.  Anyway $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}}{k!} z^k$ within the radius of convergence of the function.

Comment: You found the series for $\log(1-z)$ and will square it?  That should work.  What did you get?

Comment: I got $ln(1-z)=- \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {z^{n+1}/{n+1}}$

Comment: Use parens around the n+1 in the denominator. Curly braces do not show and lead to a misunderstanding.

Comment: @martycohen, $\dots$ yes!

Comment: @wind, We cannot edit your comments.  If you had written that in the question or if you post an answer, we could have put the braces around your denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we've found two ways to solve this.  The direct way is to find $a_4=\frac{f^{4}(0)}{4!}$.

Another way you have identified is to find the series for $g(z) = \log (1-z)$ and square it to find $f(z)=(g(z))^2.$

$$g(0)=0, \quad g^\prime(0)=\left. -\frac{1}{1-z}\right|_{z=0}=-1, \quad g^{\prime\prime}(0)=-\frac{1}{2}, \quad g^{\prime\prime\prime}(0)=-\frac{1}{3}, \quad \dots$$

$$g(z) = \log(1-z) =  -z -\frac{z^2}{2} - \frac{z^3}{3} - \cdots$$

**UPDATE**

Okay, you got $g(z)$ yourself [in the comments, after editing]!  Just carefully multiply $g(z) \cdot g(z)$ and look at the term associated with $z^4$.

$$f(z) = [g(z)]^2 = \left(-z-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{z^3}{3} - \cdots\right) \left(-z-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{z^3}{3} - \cdots\right) = z^2+z^3+\frac{11}{12} z^4 + \cdots $$

$$f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k z^k =z^2+z^3+\frac{11}{12} z^4 + \cdots $$

$$a_4 = \frac{11}{12}.$$

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- You have as an useful exercise for you the following results $$f(0)=0\\f'(0)=0\\f^{(2)}(0)=2\\f^{(3)}(0)=6\\f^{(4)}(0)=22\\f^{(5)}(0)=100\\f^{(6)}(0)=548$$
 Thus $$a_4=????$$

Comment: Multiple choice $\dots$

Comment: I assume the OP is a beginner and I wished to give him an exercise.

Comment: I am sorry, my comment could be interpreted as criticism.  I was only joking around.  Maybe I"ll give your exercise on a quiz or homework assignment, with your permission.

Comment: You have my permission obviously but I think it was not necessary. Regards.